# Ошибка в отправке Post запроса с использованием HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient

Добрый день.
Пробую отправить **Post** запрос на сервер который ожидает форму

```
   <form id="upload" class="form-group" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h3>Upload Tester</h3>
        <label for="upload-login">Login:</label>
        <input name="login" id="upload-login" type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="upload-password">Password:</label>
        <input name="password" id="upload-password" type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="file">File:</label>
        <input name="file" id="file" type="file" class="form-control">
        <button id="auth" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

Для этого использую `using System.Net.Http.HttpClient` в качестве контента `MultipartFormDataContent`. Код отправки запроса:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyPostTest().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyPostTest()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "C# Client/1.0");
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent(DefaultLogin), "login");
                content.Add(new StringContent(DefaultPassword), "password");
                var fileContent = new StreamContent(new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
                string name = Path.GetFileName(FilePath); ;
                content.Add(fileContent, "file", name);
                HttpResponseMessage response;
                try
                {
                    response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Url + Upload, content);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    throw;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("response: "+response.Content);
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
```

При выполнении запроса идет пауза (или отправляется файл или таймаут сервера 30 сек я не знаю) и выскакивает ошибка:

> System.AggregateException

В деталях которой `A task was canceled`. Этот же файл через веб форму отправляется нормально, т.е. получается ошибка в коде... Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось ошибка была в медленном интернете и времени ожидания. По умолчанию `httpClient.Timeout = 100` сек, соответственно при отправке больших файлов с медленным соединением клиент разрывал соединение через 1 мин 40 сек.
`httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)` решило проблему, ошибка перестала исчезать. Надо теперь придумать как адекватно рассчитывать время загрузки и выставлять таймаут или придумать обработчик аплоада, который бы следил за статусом загрузки.